# "top" not showing output over "ssh"

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

I am using

```
ssh user@host top
```

to show the `top` output from "host", i am getting

```
TERM environment variable not set.
```

What is the solution?

How can i run `top` on "host" like that and see output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`top` shows it's output on a terminal device, not on any standard stream (e.g. STDOUT/STDERR). As there is no terminal involved in the remote host when doing:

```
ssh user@host top
```

it's giving the error about the `TERM` environment variable not being set.

You need to allocate a pseudo TTY on the remote host using the `-t` option of `ssh`:

```
ssh -t user@host 'top'
```

Now you can send keys to `top` in the usual manner too e.g. <kbd>q</kbd> to quit, <kbd>h</kbd> for help etc.

This same solution goes for all programs that require a TTY to show output.

---

For the sake of completeness, you can allocate a pseudo TTY even if there is not local TTY involved, by using multiple `-t`s e.g.:

```
ssh -tt user@host 'top'
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing the following if you wish to see it on your local host:

`ssh user@server -t "top"` or better yet `ssh user@server -t "top -n1"` so you can get an instance of how the resources were at that moment when ran.

You can even enhance it to capture it on a file this way:

`ssh user@server -t "top -n1 -b" > topOutputFile`

Comment: You don't need an anonymous pipe and an extra process, let the shell handle this: `ssh user@server -t "top -n1 -b" >topOutputFile`

Comment: Correct thank you. Did it like that because on the first test I forgot about -b and got A LOT OF GARBAGE. Was like "What in the world?" That's why the pipe.